# Static file is not showing in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I am just learning django with static files.......Here the issue is my image is not loaded in browser its shows just like a icon here is  snapshot of output and codes that I am using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U7dX.png)plz see my images

MY codes..
Setitngs.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[STATIC_DIR,]
```

> Blockquote
> c2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load  static %}
<html
<head>

</head>
<body>
<H1> {{ title|upper }}   <br> HEllo {{ cname }}</H1>
<img src="{% static 'image/i1.png' %}" />
</body>
</html>
```

image description : this is what i get instead of full image image when hit url
urls.py (inside app folder )

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('lpy/',views.lpy),
path('ldj/',views.ldj),
]
```

my directory structure ........
[directory structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ7sn.png)

Comment: Post your `urls.py` and your project directory structure as well. Where did you put the file `i1.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [Django Documentation For Serving Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Also, to your urls.py you need to add

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

You will find this in the docs above.